# Remove Childview controller from parent viewController in ios

Tags: childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have a Parent `viewController` named "CenterViewConroller" and Child `viewController` named "InventoryViewController". I have a `UIButton` in `CenterViewController`, when i click the Button `childView` should appear at given dimension and when i again click on `parentcontroller` child view should disappear.

I am adding child view on button click as:

```
InventoryViewController *invent = [[InventoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InventoryViewController" bundle:nil];
     // iRosaAppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [invent.view setFrame:CGRectMake(400,100,320,200)];
    [self addChildViewController:invent];
    [self.view addSubview:invent.view];
    [invent didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

How do i remove `ChildView` on same button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad we can call ChildViewController and make the view hidden and when the button is clicked we can toggle the hidden property as follow.

//IN VIEWDIDLOAD
`invent = [[InventoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InventoryViewController" bundle:nil];
    [invent.view setFrame:CGRectMake(400,100,320,200)];
    [self.view addSubview:invent.view];
    invent.view.hidden = true;`

//ON BUTTON CLICK Func

`if (self.invent.view.hidden == true) {
        [self.invent.view setHidden:NO];
    } else {
        [self.invent.view setHidden:YES];
    }`

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.**

In CenterViewController.h file
create a object for InventoryViewController class

InventoryViewController *invent;

**Step 2.**
In CenterViewController.m file

Create following method

```
-(void)addInventoryViewController

{

invent = [[InventoryViewController alloc]       
  initWithNibName:@"InventoryViewController" bundle:nil];

[invent.view setFrame:CGRectMake(400,100,320,200)];
[self addChildViewController:invent];
[self.view addSubview:invent.view];
[invent didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

**Step 3.**
On you button click action method

```
-(IBAction)onButtonClick:(id)sender

{

if(invent != nil)
  {

 [invent.view removeFromSuperview];
 invent = nil;



}



 else

  {

     [self addInventoryViewController];

  }

}
```